# Listener not working on linearlayout which contain Edittext

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an EditText contained in a LinearLayout. For My project I have set an OnclickListener on the LinearLayout. When I launch application nothing happened on click to layout. Maybe It due to the EditText but need that OnCliclistener to be work on LenearLayout.

MyCode:

### XML

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lnlabelnameuniteholder"
        android:id="@+id/choix_decategorie"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <EditText
            android:text="@string/choix_de_categorie"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#000" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

### CODE

```
    maCategorie = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.choix_decategorie);



           maCategorie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            MyDB db = new MyDB(MyActivityCategorie.this);
            ArrayList<Category> categoryList = db.getCategory();

            ChoiceCategoryDialog categoryDialog = new ChoiceCategoryDialog(MyActivityCategorie.this, R.string.add_category, mCategoryTextView.getText().toString(), categoryList, MyActivityCategorie.this, true);
            categoryDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: provide code of activity and xml, please. Also, please, specify: do you want to react on every click to LinearLayout or only for those, that not collide with edit text area?

Comment: Question is not clear. Also add some code that you are trying along with the question for better understanding

Comment: I have update the question with the code. I hope It will be clear

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are referring to R.id.choix_decategorie (which is not shown in your code, is this a LinearLayout you want to set onClickListener on?

For a LinearLayout that has child elements (like yours does) - may need to prevent the child elements from receiving focus - you can set `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/choix_decategorie"
        android:id="@+id/lnpriceholderlabel"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
```

For a good measure you may also set  `android:clickable="false"` on each of the child elements. So your layout would look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/choix_decategorie"
        android:id="@+id/lnpriceholderlabel"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <EditText
            android:text="@string/choix_de_categorie"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#000" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Give it a try and let us know if this works.

Comment: I Have tried, the Editext don't have focus but when I click nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
LinearLayout yourLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.yourID);
        yourLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // remember to use "View."
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

set LinearLayout attribute `android:clickable="true"`

if you have button or textview in layout set `android:clickable="false"` for all of them

Answer (score 0):

You must have to set the LinearLayout clickable="true"

`<LineartLayout....
   android:clickable="true"...>`

This will work

And you need to put some margins in EditText, because EditText comes upside on LinearLayout and space doesn't remain for LinearLayout to be clickable.

put

`<EditText
    android:layout_margin="5dp".../>`

Comment: It will not working, because method setOnClickListener() enabling clickable flag.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could do something like this (kotlin code):

```
editText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_NULL
editText.setOnClickListener { linearLayout.performClick() }
```

In that case the editText won't pop up the keyboard and the linearLayout will receive the a click event.